# How do I deserialize to object with default formatter in net core 5 webapi when supporting multipart/form-data?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

If I make a typical controller and action, with a parameter that comes from the body, the webapi will deserialize the body content into an instance of the class type using the appropriate deserializer, based on the content-type header:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]

public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class MyObject
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public void Test([FromBody] MyObject value)
    {
    }
}
```

If I make a request to it, the request looks like this if using json:

```
POST https://localhost:44380/Message HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44380
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://localhost:44380/swagger/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

{"Text":"123 abc 123"}
```

Or this if xml (my web api is set up to support json and xml):

```
POST https://localhost:44380/Message HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44380
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 82
accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/*+xml
Referer: https://localhost:44380/swagger/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyObject>
    <Text>string</Text>
</MyObject>
```

If I am changing my webapi to use multipart mime, I can't rely on the automated deserialization of the content body.  As I loop through each part,  how would I deserialize each sections content based on the content-type header and the configured formatters of the webapi?  I could hard code a specific serializer but I'd like to use what's configured.

```
var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(Request.ContentType.Boundary).Value;

MultipartReader reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

while (section != null)
{
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDispositionHeaderValue = section.GetContentDispositionHeader();
    
    Stream strData = null;
    if (contentDispositionHeaderValue.IsFileDisposition())
    {
        FileMultipartSection fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
        strData = fileSection.FileStream;
        fileName = fileSection.FileName;
        name = fileSection.Name;
    }
    else if (contentDispositionHeaderValue.IsFormDisposition())
    {
        FormMultipartSection formSection = section.AsFormDataSection();
        name = formSection.Name;
        strData = section.Body;
    }
    
    //How to deserialize strData to MyObject using the webap's configured formatters?
    
    section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
}
```

Comment: I feel like you're trying to customize the model binding but it's not clear why you want to customize it. Anyway, customizing the model binding should be done via `IModelBinder` and `IModelBinderProvider`.

Comment: @KingKing - how would I consume a multipart request without customizing the model binding?

Comment: I've never done something like that, actually by following its standard way, you have access to some context (e.g: `ModelBindingContext`) which may be helpful. Otherwise technically you need to ***select*** the `IInputFormatter` (corresponding with the format you want) to invoke its `ReadAsync` manually. It requires a complicated context however. I would dig into the source code of model binding to see how `IInputFormatter`s are used but really I'm fairly busy now.

Comment: one extensibility point for you is the `BodyModelBinder` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinder.cs - It requires a request stream reader. You need to somehow inject your stream (not always the request body stream) so after that the remaining logic just works. By default, the implementations of `IInputFormatter` always try reading from the request body stream (using a request stream reader factory).

Comment: you can try overriding the reader factory, its `CreateReader` accepts a `Stream` (which I think will always be the request body stream), you override that to ***ignore*** that stream and use your own stream (prepared by your code above, stored in the `strData`). I think it's possible but of course you need to try to make sure it works.